# Apply to all sites *where I have this avatar* pls

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2013

I use a couple of different avatars. My Meta Stallman Beard is great, but I don't want it all over my Arqade Miniature-giant-space-hamster. Can the default 'apply all' button only do so for sites with the same avatar?

Comment: I'm thinking that for the period of time that Winterbash is going to run for that this is a little far fetched, albeit a nice idea. Maybe get it on the list of features for Winterbash 2014? :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great idea, but Flyk is correct - it's probably too big of a feature and too late now to include it in this year's Winter Bash. I'll put it on the list of things to remember for next year.

Comment: I want to get a hat this year so I can see if this feature is a thing now!